# UploadStream method for Azure storage not working from remote clients

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.Net web api, that uses the uploadStream method, it works when I upload files from the local machine. But when I call the web api from a remote client it doesn't seem to stream the file from the remote system. I can see the api being called but nothing is getting transferred. There are no errors.
Any help is welcome.
Below is a snippet of my code:-

```
var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
int FileTimeOut = 3600;
BlobRequestOptions blobReqOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
blobReqOptions.MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(FileTimeOut);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
blob.UploadFromStream(stream, null, blobReqOptions, null);
```

Comment: There should not be any such difference. Please recheck on below points 1. Are you able to see the stream properly posted to your API? Debug and match the stream length with your file size. 2. As it is not mandatory to give MaxExecutionTime, check this without any time out mentioned. 3. If possible, have a fiddler running on your WebAPI machine to make sure the call is made to blob storage for upload and capture the exact error message for this call, if it is failing.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check with fiddler and the stream length.

Comment: Don't see any calls to Azure using fiddler. Looks like an issue with IIS

Comment: I narrowed it down to UploadFromStream method, is not working for uploading files. It fails with an error "Unable to connect to the remote server", which is weird because I can connect to Azure get the container name. When I try to use "UploadFromStream" it fails.